# item index start from 1 in next pages in Mat-pagination

Tags: angular-material

My mat-table has n number of rows. and I have mat-paginator.  The items will display in each page with index 1 to 5. I need 1 to 5 in 1st page , next page index should start from 6.

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 showFirstLastButtons
                 [pageSize]="itemsPerPage"
                 [pageIndex]="currentPage"
                 aria-label="Select page of emailObj elements"
                 >
  </mat-paginator>
```

here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-biepp3-jxdm5f?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ (index + 1) + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize) }}
```

This solved my problem

Comment: where do you add this